# C++ : Trim a string to a single char, then turn that char into a float

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing a program that takes a polynomial expression from a file, and then solves the polynomial using the variable provided. Example :

f(5.0) = 7x^2 – 9

So basically I'm extracting a file line by line by doing :

```
string line;
getline(inputfile,line);
```

Now, I need to get the variable inside of f (in this case 5) and set that equal to a float which I've named variable. I'm aware of atof (I'm using minGW 4.9.2 [required for my programming class]) so I can't use stof. My current attempt at extracting this float looks like this :

```
float variable;

for(int i = 0; i<line.length(); i++) {
      if(isdigit(line[i]) {
           variable = atof(line[i]) // THE ERROR IS HERE
           break; // so we only get the first digit
      }
}
```

I'm pretty lost here, not sure what to do. I just need to set that 5.0 (or whatever it may be) equal to my variable float. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to convert a single digit into a number then subtract `'0'` from that char and you have it.

Comment: Have you tried `man atof` or google atof?

Comment: This is a classic example of a question that's too broad. Why? Because it's actually two questions glued together: trimming a string and converting a number represented as a char to a float. Both questions already have (many) existing answers here on SO.

Comment: is `line` a `char[]`/`char*`/`std::string`? If so, you are just converting one character which I doubt if it is what you want to do.  Learn to properly break down the string first

Answer (score 2):

It probably does duty for your intent.

```
string str = "f(5.0) = 7x^2 – 9";
string startDEL = "(";
string stopDEL =  ")";
unsigned first = str.find(startDEL);
unsigned last = str.find(stopDEL);
string strNew = str.substr (first+1,last-first-1);

std::cout << << atof(strNew.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: string.find returns `size_type`, not `unsigned`

Comment: This question is marked c++11 so you should use `auto first = ...` instead of a specific type. Or even better `const auto first = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::streamstream`, which allows you to treat a `std::string` as a stream:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(inputfile, str);

std::istringstream is(str);
float f, char x, char op, float second_var;
is >> f >> x >> op; >> second_var; // Read 7, then x, then ^, then 2.
```

Comment: He needs to parse the 5.0 from f(5.0) and not expression part!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shortest solution is to use std::stringstream:

```
char dummy;
double variable;
std::stringstream("f(5.2) = 7x^2-9") >> dummy >> dummy >> variable;
```

This will read the first two chars into dummy and the following numeric value into variable.

You have to `#include <sstream>` to be able to use std::stringstream.

Answer (score -1):

try strtof instead of atof(), since atof() returns a double instead of a float